# Where have the corner handles gone in keynote?

Tags: macos, presentations, iwork-keynote

If I add a text box in keynote then I can only resize it horizontally. If I create a new slide and apply a master style with bullet points or text then I get a box with corner and vertical handles as well.

How can I insert one of these? Or can I convert a normal text box to this type?

Cheers

Comment: There's usually no need: Text boxes automatically resize when adding additional lines.

Comment: the difference is trying to animate a normal text box of bullets does not allow me the "by bullet group" option so I need a "bullet box"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy&paste or *Duplicate* one of the larger ones once you have entered some text.

Comment: I was hoping for something more elegant really, I understand that this is an option though, thanks

Comment: @Simon I don't know how to *create* them, but you also asked for how to *insert*. This is easy. `Cmd-V` :-)

Answer (score 2):

I've finally found the correct answer after trying all the suggested above.

Create new text box. Right click on the text box. (or control click)
Choose make editable.
This will give it red adjustment handles. Don't touch anything as it will skew your text box. 
Just hit enter.

Now the text box has all of the handles. You can make it as tall or short as you want and " Shrink text to fit" becomes an option in the right hand menu pane.

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the similar problem and found a solution. What you need to do is to shrink the size to 50% so that you can see the outside of the slide, then double click on the edge of the text box and it should bring up all four sides with tiny adjustment buttons.